# Python: Create an instance of a class at runtime based on user input

Tags: python

I'm somewhat new to python, and have been searching for info on this all day. I want to be able to ask the user how many instances they want, and based on their input, create as many instances of a class as they requested.

I would also like to be able to have the name of each instance be based off of input such as asking the person's name or something.

```
NumPlayers = input("How many people are playing? ")
for i in range(0, int(NumPlayers)-1):
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    name = Player()
```

This would be similar to `John = Player()` but "John" would be whatever name the user gave us, and there would be however many players the user wants.

From my research today, it seems that allowing people to determine the name of their own instances isn't a good idea, so at this point I'm thinking something more along the lines of this:

```
NumPlayers = input("How many people are playing? ")
for i in range(0, int(NumPlayers)-1):
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    Player+i = Player(name)
```

This would be the same as `Player1 = Player("John")` etc. for more players. Is this something that is possible? It's really stumping me. Just to clarify a few things, the class itself is already in the code, in the provided code Player is a class that has already been defined with methods and everything.

Comment: Note that [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) reserves ``CapWords`` for classes, so ``NumPlayers`` is a bad name for a local variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a data structure, specifically, a [list](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq).

```
no_players = input("How many people are playing? ")
players = []
for _ in range(int(no_players)):
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    players.append(Player(name))
```

This will produce a list of `[Player(...), Player(...), ...]`. This can be indexed (`players[2]`) or iterated over (`for player in players:`) among other operations. I recommend you read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) for more.

As a side note, some lists can be constructed even more nicely with a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).

Comment: I had no idea there was a way to instantiate something besides a simple X = something(), Thanks a bunch. Append vs. Extend has always been a bit tricky for me, so this is super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As Lattyware suggested you are looking for a list to put your players into.
May I suggest to modify slightly your procedure to accept as many players as you want as long as they put a new name?

```
players = []
while True:
    playername = input("Insert a new player (empty to begin):")
    if playername:
        players.append(Player(playername))
    else:
        break
```